# How to collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS using IN operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to filter records on 'Email' my query is like this.

```
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM Customer)
```

It gives me following error

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict
>   between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
>   and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the
>   equal to operation.

I can use collate if there is equal operator (=) instead of IN. But using Collate here gives me syntax error.

> SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE email NOT IN
>   (SELECT email FROM Customer) collate
>   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

How can I resolve this. I can't drop and re create tables because it is live db.

Data in #temp table is from SQL Server 2000 and Customer table is in SQL Server 2005

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
...
NOT IN (SELECT email COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS email FROM Customer)
```

The collate bit follows the column name, basically.

Or this (it depends on which one you want):

```
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE email collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT IN (SELECT email FROM Customer)
```

Finally, if your DB is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, one option is to use `...COLLATE Database_Default...` to coerce to a default setting.