# SQL Server: Case-Sensitive matching?

Tags: sql-server, case-sensitive

Given an existing SQL Server database, and limited power over changing things, is there any way to implement a case-sensitive match?

By limited power, the user has no option to re-install the database or change the collation in any way.

I understand the convenience of case-insensitivity, but sometimes you need to work with data where case is significant.

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004363/how-to-collate-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-using-in-operator

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `COLLATE` clause with a case-sensitive collation to coerce a case-sensitive compare:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Example
WHERE 
    Col1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = 'A';
```

However, that will result in a [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expression so an index on the column won't be able to be used efficiently (e.g. scan rather than seek). Consider also specifying the predicate without the `COLLATE` so that an index seek can be used and rows also filtered based on the case-sensitivity.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Example
WHERE 
    Col1 = 'A' 
    AND col1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = 'A';
```

Comment: Sorry — non-sargable?

Comment: @Manngo, I added a link with the definition of non-sargable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable